# PHP Error in File Upload Preferences after upgrade

Tags: upgrade, php-errors

After upgrading from 1.6.3 to 2.9.0, I'm getting the following errors when I try to bring up the Site Upload Preferences:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #2 is not an array
Filename: models/file_upload_preferences_model.php
Line Number: 111

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #2 is not an array
Filename: models/file_upload_preferences_model.php
Line Number: 111

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/mysite.com/system/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)
Filename: core/Common.php
Line Number: 442
```

My issue started with the fact that I was using Mark Hout's File extension, and I was going to try to implement this fix:

https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/218268/

and I needed to get the upload directory's ID from the File Upload Preferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my issue. Something during the upgrade process inserted this line into my system/expressionengine/config/config.php file:

```
$config['upload_preferences'] = 'Array';
```

I commented that out and no more errors. Hope this helps someone else.